# Approximate expression under square root

Tags: approximation, radicals

Given $x>>1,$ how can the expression 
\begin{equation}
\left(1-\frac{1}{4x^2}\right)^{1/2}
\end{equation}
be approximated to \begin{equation}
\left(1-\frac{1}{8x^2}\right)?
\end{equation}

Comment: Maclaurin series of $\sqrt{1-t}$?

Comment: If $f(t)=t^{1/2}$ then $f'(1)=1/2$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}
1-\frac{1}{4x^2} &\approx 1-\frac{1}{4x^2}+\frac{1}{64x^4}\\
&= \left (1-\frac{1}{8x^2}\right)^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=1-1/4x^2$. Then $(1-1/8x^2)^2=y+1/64x^4=y(1+1/64x^4y)>y.$ So$$ y^{1/2}<1-1/8x^2=y^{1/2}(1+1/64x^4y)^{1/2}<y^{1/2}(1+1/128x^4 y).$$  Even for the weak restriction $x\geq 1$ we have $1>y\geq 3/4, $ so  the proportionate error is less than $1/128x^4y,$ which is at most $1/ 96 x^4$.

Also $y^{1/2}<1, $ and hence  for the value of the error, if $x\geq 1$ we have
 $$0<y^{1/2}-(1-1/8x^2)<y^{1/2}(1/128z^4 y)\leq y^{1/2}(1/96 x^4)<1/96x^4.$$